# Write Cookies and set cookies value as text box select Vlaue

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am trying to store the selected value of a dropdown list in a cookies which work perfectly with this code.

```
protected void state_DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie StudentCookies = new HttpCookie("userloaction_cookies");
        StudentCookies.Value = state_DropDownList.SelectedValue;
        StudentCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1000);
        Response.Cookies.Add(StudentCookies);
    }
```

I then want to use the cookie value to set the select value for the dropdown list after page_load. It works, but I cannot change the dropdown value after the first value has been stored in the cookies.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if (Request.Cookies["userloaction_cookies"] != null)
     {
            HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["userloaction_cookies"];
            string cookiesvalue = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
            state_DropDownList.SelectedValue = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
     }
```

I think the issue is that the Page_load method triggers before the state_DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged method.

Is there any possible way of making this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page load triggers first on each post back.

You will need to check the value of [IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is how:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["userloaction_cookies"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["userloaction_cookies"];
        string cookiesvalue = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
        state_DropDownList.SelectedValue = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
    }
```

}